# Adobe 9 Check box required field

Tags: pdf, adobe

I've created reports in Adboe that have checkobxes and set then to required fields.

But when i click the submit button all fields but the check boxes are validated.

I.e 
If i dont complete the required textbox field the report will not submit, but when i do and the required checkbox fields are not checked it still submits.

This only appears to be happening on Adobe 9

Any ideas?

Thanks
Sp

Here is a link to a test page
http://www.mediafire.com/?mnkmmlime2f

If you fill the text box with anything it will submit regardless of the check box status (which is also a required field)

Comment: Adobe what..? Photoshop, Acrobat, InDesign, Flash...

Comment: Depending on the definition of 'required'... But the checkbox is there, and in a valid state (off), so it makes sense to me.

Comment: It's adobe reader. I've dropped the check box control onto the page and set its "Required field" to true. but it still submits even when it's not checked I need the box to be checked before it submits

Comment: Is there anyway i can tell it that the check box must be checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out.

Adobe Reader checkbox allows has a value (default "false") so when the form validates it sees the checkbox as having a value.

I've had to write some java to stop the form submitting if the checkbox has a null/False/false value

This works like a dream

Thanks for trying to help wit hthis post all

```
var f;
var Valid = "1";
for (var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++)
{
    f = this.getField(this.getNthFieldName(i));

        if (f.type == 'checkbox')
        {
            if(f.required == true)
            {

         if(f.value == "false" || f.value == "False" || f.value == "null")
                {
 Valid = "0";
                 }
            }
        }

}; 

if(Valid == "1")
{
this.submitForm('');
}
else
{
app.alert("Please complete all required fields");
}
```